# Flagging outliers of repeated measures within group (given there are thousands of groups)

Tags: r, outliers

I want to identify misreported values from a school district. There are 10,000 school districts, and I've collected 14 years worth of school districts and the average amount they spend per student each year. If the preceding five years, the values are within a range of 6 - $9000, but then in the following year, 2013, that school district (and its corresponding city) report a per student spending of $15,000; there's a good chance, for whatever reason, that that value is misreported. There are ways of tracking down the correct value, but that $15000 is likely misrepresentative and shouldn't be used.

I have created a large dataset to look at education expenditure (how much a school district spends per student) and crime rate, so I have repeating values of city, county, school district over a 14-year period. I’ve looked at the max/min for the dataset for school district per student spending (and have looked at scatterplots), and have identified anomalies. This made me realize that there could be misreported school district expenditures that aren’t extreme for the dataset (though they are extreme among that particular school district).

If I wanted to flag values as misreported based on standard deviation, I could use:

```
flags<-
  dat%>%
    group_by(full_district_id)%>%
    mutate(sd.district_id = sd(EXPENDITURE_PER_STUDENT, na.rm = TRUE),
    flag = ifelse(full_district_id > 2* sd.district_id, "greater",
    ifelse(full_district_id< 2 * sd.district_id, "smaller", "nothing"))%>%
    ungroup()%>%
    filter(flag == "greater"|flag == "smaller")
```

but I think it would be better to look at the preceding year (or something like the five preceding years) to see whether that particular year is an anomaly. So if a value is greater that $4000 more than any of the preceding five years then that value would be flagged. I’m uncertain how to write a conditional that would say something like if over $4000 from the previous x years of school district expenditure, then flag this value. And then I review these values and look for their correct values.

I googled various things but none were really what I was looking for.

Here is a small chunk of my dataset, so you can get a feel for what is going on; though for reference, it is over 100,000 values.
 
Thanks much!

dput of data

```
structure(list(year = c(2003, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2003, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2009, 
2010, 2011), PLACE_ID = c("0100124", "0100124", "0100124", "0100124", 
"0100124", "0100124", "0100124", "0100124", "0100124", "0100124", 
"0100124", "0100124", "0100124", "0100460", "0100460", "0100460", 
"0100460", "0100460", "0100460", "0100460"), CITY = c("abbeville", 
"abbeville", "abbeville", "abbeville", "abbeville", "abbeville", 
"abbeville", "abbeville", "abbeville", "abbeville", "abbeville", 
"abbeville", "abbeville", "adamsville", "adamsville", "adamsville", 
"adamsville", "adamsville", "adamsville", "adamsville"), COUNTY_ID = c("01067", 
"01067", "01067", "01067", "01067", "01067", "01067", "01067", 
"01067", "01067", "01067", "01067", "01067", "01073", "01073", 
"01073", "01073", "01073", "01073", "01073"), full_district_id = c("0101740", 
"0101740", "0101740", "0101740", "0101740", "0101740", "0101740", 
"0101740", "0101740", "0101740", "0101740", "0101740", "0101740", 
"0101920", "0101920", "0101920", "0101920", "0101920", "0101920", 
"0101920"), EXPENDITURE_PER_STUDENT = c(6.91392685629849, 6.80427570954663, 
7.42387732749179, 7.80973129992738, 8.57273726639795, 8.14466546112116, 
7.91766361717101, 7.57727272727273, 7.50594166366583, 7.91607343574372, 
8.26783670354826, 8.4435736677116, 8.48149606299213, 5.93085371942087, 
6.31827864279556, 7.21194954512474, 7.96307522733535, 8.61417039862885, 
9.07166232181485, 8.87169548243168)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Comment: So what exactly do you want here. Is it specifically code to check "if over 3 ($3000) from the previous year"? So what's the desired result for this sample input. There is no precise definition for "outlier" so you will need to clearly define what you are after in the question. Otherwise this is just too broad to be answered here.

Comment: Interesting problem, very broad question. Have you considered modelling this data in some way (mixed model for example) and look at the difference in predicted and observed value?

Comment: Hi, @Wietze314, yes, I will be using a crossed, mixed-effects model. Perhaps I could've been clearer with "outlier." I've found a handful of instances where values were reported wrong, either by the school district, itself, or by the Census. There's also a chance that enrollment dropped significantly, etc. So I'm looking for a way to set aside values that deviate largely from the preceding year. For instance, if the eight previous years, there is a range of $8000-$12000, but then the following year, the school district reports $18000, there is a good chance that that value is not accurate.

Comment: This value isn't so high that it would be visible in looking at the entire dataset, but it would still be inaccurate and would affect the data.

Comment: Rewrote parts of the question...hopefully it is clearer.

Comment: I would then calculate the relative increase, from the previous year and/or the relative decrease in the following year.

Answer (score 0):

The following defines the outliers for each district_id and keeps the rows, in which the expenditure per student is not an outlier (defined for each district separately):

```
library(dplyr)
library(outliers)
View(df %>%
      group_by(full_district_id) %>%
       arrange(year)%>% 
        filter(!EXPENDITURE_PER_STUDENT %in% c(outlier(EXPENDITURE_PER_STUDENT))))
```